# Exception in thread "Gfsh Launcher" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/History in gemfire gfsh 8.2.1

Tags: gemfire

Having this exception when trying to do import/export data with gfsh 8.2.1. The other commands is working fine (e.g. query, list, etc.).
The import/export command is successfully executed (I can see the file gets created) with Exception. I can see I have the jline2.11 on both gfsh and gemfire server classpath.

Any help is appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Gfsh Launcher" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/History
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.i18n.CliStrings.<clinit>(CliStrings.java:400)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.commands.DataCommands.exportData(DataCommands.java:866)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.util.spring.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:51)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.remote.RemoteExecutionStrategy.execute(RemoteExecutionStrategy.java:105)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.remote.CommandProcessor.executeCommand(CommandProcessor.java:97)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.remote.CommandStatementImpl.process(CommandStatementImpl.java:59)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.remote.MemberCommandService.processCommand(MemberCommandService.java:47)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.beans.MemberMBeanBridge.processCommand(MemberMBeanBridge.java:1737)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.beans.MemberMBean.processCommand(MemberMBean.java:400)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.beans.MemberMBean.processCommand(MemberMBean.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.History
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.Launcher.parseOptions(Launcher.java:231)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.Launcher.parseCommandLine(Launcher.java:239)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency conflict for spring-shell, check the gfsh-dependencies manifest to use the correct version. In my case it's spring-shell.1.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Dien, are the import/export commands executed successfully? Is 8.2.1 the version you are using? I've tried import/export in 8.2.1.2 and I am not seeing the exception. Have you tried with the latest patch?

Comment: question in answer?

Comment: I'm using the latest version from Pivotal website 8.2.1. I don't where do you get the version 8.2.1.2? this is my MD5 for the gemfire.jar file: D64E802F571E1FB0BEEE77BEDE2C2F29